# Spinner get position and do different action for each selection

Tags: android, spinner, selection

I am trying to use a spinner, save the position of each selection and depend on this, another spinner with different selections for each position appears..
I made the first spinner with the help of [the spinner docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) but then I can't do something different for each selection.. Is there anyone who can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: attach the code and data which you wanna show for each selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement in the `onItemSelected()` method:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                //do action for first selection
                break;
            case 1:
                //do action for second selection
                break;
            ...

        }
    }
```

Comment: It was much easier than I thought... Thank you, I was stucked!!

Answer (score 0):

it is too simple to impliment:
try spinner ItemSelectedListener.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
if(position==0){}//do the function you want to perform
else if(position==1){}//And so on
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }

});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `if` since it is computationally more expensive, it has to do many more checks, depending on the elements in the spinner, use `switch` instead